# Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 Server keeps crashing - Network related

Tags: networking, server, crash

I have a Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS server which has been running fine for months. This runs as a VM on Hyper-V.

Since 2 days ago it keeps crashing. After some debugging it seems it crashes unless I either (a) remove the network card from the VM or (b) boot into recovery mode where I can run networking without it crashing.

So, it looks like there's something odd going on with networking that is causing it to crash.

How do I go about starting to diagnose and fix this?

I'm wondering if it's an updated package that is causing the issue?

Comment: What do your logs in /var/log say? If seeking a possible update culprit, look in /var/log/apt

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in kernel 4.15-60. Downgrading to -58 works fine, or upgrading to v5. Lots of people seem to be having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that I was having a similar issue and upgrading the kernel to v5 fixed it. In my case I was running 18.04.3 on bare metal and using various Docker containers.

Basically my issue was the same as this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1842447

Since upgrading to v5 with `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04` I've been crash free for ~24 hours.

This also has relevant info https://github.com/mailcow/mailcow-dockerized/issues/2904

I know this answer is more specific to Docker but it isn't really a Docker issue. Kernel 4.15-60 broke something with networking, there is already a fix committed for kernel 4.15-62 but that hasn't been released yet. I'd avoid kernel 4.15-60.